# Opportunity Owner Full Name is not working on Reports

Tags: reporting

I created the following formula in a report but the owner full name is always empty, so the result value is always 2 instead of 1.

Here is an example of the code:

`IF(FULL_NAME=='Mark Anderson',1,2)`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to save it ? the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Json Yes I was able to save it. Why the syntax is wrong?

Comment: Summary Formula supports only numeric fields, you can't reference text fields.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the formula within the report? pls make sure to include the report type.

Comment: It is a matrix report grouped by Opportunity Owner, but as you mentioned it is not working because is not possible to reference text fields like FULL_NAME=='Mark Anderson' in summary formulas.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce it with a Summary report SF would not let me save it, hence my first question.

Comment: @json Finally I think is not possible to do this the way I want, so I will try to find another workaround.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved with summary formulas on reports.

I wasn't able to find a source that states what summary formula **can't** support,  only what it can:

> Regardless of the summary formula data type, your summary formula can
> contain fields of different data types, including: number, currency,
> percent, and checkbox (true/false) fields.
>
> [Source: [Get the Most Out of Summary Formulas: Tips, Limits, and Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_csf_tips.htm&type=5)]

Another way to achieve what you want, is to create a custom formula that returns text on the Opportunity Object.